# With WebKit GTK, how do I open a link in an external browser?

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

I am writing an application using the GTK implementation of WebKit and Python. In my app I render some  links but when the user clicks the link in my WebKit view it loads the linked page inside the webkit view. I instead want the link to open in the system's default web browser.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

First you want to intercept when the user clicks on any link rendered by webkit. See [navigation-policy-decision-requested](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-navigation-policy-decision-requested).

Second you want to reject that request and make a request to the host OS to open the requested link using the default browser. For that you can see this [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue3177) as a starting point.

Comment: Many thanks, holygeek! I can now pull out the URI from the link. Do you know how I can then block the link from loading in the WebKit widget so I can send it to the browser?

Comment: Call the Python equivalent of `webkit_web_policy_decision_ignore()` on the policy decision object that is passed to the `navigation-policy-decision-requested` signal.